# lubuntu - audio drives not recognized

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

I typed `sudo dpkg -l | grep -e alsa -e pulseaudio` again, and got this:

```
ii alsa-base 1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu4 all ALSA driver configuration files 
ii alsa-utils 1.0.25-4ubuntu2 i386 Utilities for configuring and using ALSA 
ii gnome-alsamixer 0.9.7~cvs.20060916.ds.1-3ubuntu1 i386 ALSA sound mixer for GNOME
ii gstreamer0.10-alsa:i386 0.10.36-1.1ubuntu1 i386 GStreamer plugin for ALSA 
ii gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio:i386 0.10.31-3+nmu1ubuntu2 i386 GStreamer plugin for PulseAudio 
ii pulseaudio 1:3.0-0ubuntu6 i386 PulseAudio sound server 
ii pulseaudio-module-x11 1:3.0-0ubuntu6 i386 X11 module for PulseAudio sound server    
ii pulseaudio-utils 1:3.0-0ubuntu6 i386 Command line tools for the PulseAudio sound server
```

---

After the commands in 2., pulseaudio is working again, but there is still no sound.. I tried the command in 3., and here is what I got:

```
~$ sudo gedit /etc/default/speech-dispatcher

sudo: gedit: command not found
```

Comment: Edit your question and post the output of `sudo dpkg -l | grep -e alsa -e pulseaudio`

Answer (score 0):

**It seems from the output is that many alsamixer and pulseaudio packages are missing**

I suggestion you to re-install it. To re-install execute following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -f install --reinstall alsa-utils pulseaudio gnome-alsamixer
```

Restart you system.

Reply if you get any error.

**Edit**

If above doesn't help that much then try following:

First execute `alsamixer` in terminal and check that you don't have **MM** under the vertical bars listed there. If you get any **MM** you can go to that bar using <kbd>Left</kbd> or <kbd>Right</kbd> arrow key and press <kbd>M</kbd> to un-mute the sound. If you get the sound then better or else go for following options.

1. Execute `sudo alsa force-reload` in terminal

   Wait for few seconds. It will show some text and looks like it still re-loading. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to exit and restart your system. You should get your sound. Still doesn't work then go to 2nd option.
2. Execute following command to remove and then install packages

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio
   sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean
   sudo apt-get -f install alsa-base pulseaudio
   ```

   And force reload Alsa again:

   ```
   sudo alsa force-reload
   ```

   Then restart your system. If still it doesn't work then go for 3rd option.
3. Open the terminal and edit `speech-dispatcher` file by using the following command:

   ```
   sudo gedit /etc/default/speech-dispatcher
   ```

   On the opened window change `RUN=yes` to `RUN=no`

   Again reboot your system.

Hope any of the listed options would help you. Reply if something goes wrong.